# Can I formulaically generate a delimited list for data validation, without using cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Can I formulaically generate a delimited list for data validation, without using cells?

Like, how, if you activate Data Validation in a cell, you can validate against a typed list, instead of a set of cells.

A list, like "A,B,C".

But, I want to validate against a list of years, about 40 entries long, about 1970, to the current year.

And while I could of course, go manual, like, "1970, 1971, ..."

I'm wonder if there's any formula I can put for Data Validation, which would generate that list in an easier way, and I don't want to use cells, because I don't want to keep track of any more. I'm using enough already...